# Getting CFAdmin Mail Server in code

Tags: coldfusion, mail-server, cfadmin

I've specified a Mail Server in my CFAdmin I want to get it in my code. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: What do you mean?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to concede I've never had to specifically do what you need to do, but CF has an Admin API.  Details are on the [Administrator API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fcf.html) page in the docs.

Relevant extract:

> mail.cfc Manage ColdFusion mail settings.

I reckon that's what yer after.

Comment: Actually Peter raises a good point.  We're both interpreting your question in a different way.  It might be best to be a bit more descriptive as to what you're actually after.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike datasources, mail servers are used automatically - you don't need to specify them.

However, you can also supply the assorted properties for a mail server directly as attributes on a [cfmail](http://cfdocs.org/cfmail) tag, which then overrides those in the administrator for that instance only.

*(If this isn't what you're asking, you need to edit your question to clarify and add more information.)*

Comment: You are right. But for some reason, I have to programmatically know that what Mail Server settings have been specified in my CfAdmin. I was wondering if there is a way to read CFAdmin settings in my code.

Comment: _"for some reason"_ makes no sense - there's either an explicit reason or there isn't - but Adam's answer indicates how to retrieve the settings stored in the Administrator.

Comment: @AdilMalik This does not make sense to me either.  If you know you will need to dynamically specify the mail server in the code then just supply the attributes in your code as Peter suggested instead of trying to read the admin settings.